# Fast way to find a value in many TIFF files

Tags: python

I have a very large number of TIFF files with values {0...255}.  I want to find which files have one or more elements of a particular value, say 11.

What is a fast way in Python to find which files in a large number of TIFF files contain a particular value?

I could do something like this

```
import tifffile
import glob

for file in glob.glob("/home/user/data/*.tif"):
    tiff = tifffile.imread(file)
    if tiff[tiff == 11].shape[0] != 0:
        print(file)
```

but is there a faster way?

Comment: Is that way currently too slow? I'm not implying that it's premature optimization for you to want to see if there's a faster way, it'd just potentially be helpful for others if they knew your reasons for wanting this.

Comment: When I say a "very large number" I mean tens of thousands of files.  Currently I'm looking at 2D one channel files but 2D 20 channel files are coming up shortly.